# Force update of a virtual CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl containings about 2500 differents elements consisting of a 48x48 icon and text.

Due to the amount of data I implemented it as a virtual list providing

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_GETDISPINFO, IDC_LST_ICONS, &CWGDIconSearchDlg::OnLvnGetdispinfoLstIcons)
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ODFINDITEM, IDC_LST_ICONS, &CWGDIconSearchDlg::OnLvnOdfinditemLstIcons)
```

My problem is when I change list content these callback get never called.

How can I force it?

Comment: Use code tags next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows cannot know that you have changed an item in virtual list.

In order to trigger a redraw of your CListCtrl, you must call `yourcontrol.Invalidate()` which will trigger a repaint of your control.

Comment: An alternative, if only one or a few items have changed, is to call `RedrawItems(first, last)`. This avoids the flicker sometimes created by redrawing the entire control window.